# Is it possible to install a J2ME application on a mobile that does not support the language mobile requires (like persian language)?

Tags: localization, java-me, mobile-application, persian

**Situation:** I want to get a very simple J2ME mobile application developed that uses Persian language displaying the label and text, and this is to be installed on any mobile that runs J2ME (like nokia 1280).

**Question:** Is it possible to use Persian fonts and embed it in such a way that it is independent of mobile device (i.e. does not care if mobile has Persian language installed) or do we need to use png images as labels?

Comment: You can't embed fonts, as far as I remember (j2me is pretty ancient...). You can use bitmaps though: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_create_custom_fonts_in_Java_ME

Comment: Persian language has different shapes for one single character depending on whether the character is at the beginning/middle/end of a word. Does bitmap support it? (Let's ignore that bitmap is not efficient since it loads everytime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard MIDP2.1 and CLDC 1.1 doesn't have classes to let you use TTF fonts. The typical way of doing it, is to use a bitmap font. Bitmap fonts are fast to render, and lets you use a lot of colours (if you wish). The downside of bitmap fonts is that, in order to support multiple screen resolutions, you'll have create different sizes of the font.

http://mobilefonts.sourceforge.net/

But like any other platform, someone has of course developed a TTF library for JavaME (called TTME)

http://www.xiteapplet.de/

I remember checking out TTME some time back, and as expected TTF rendering is slow. (Because most JavaME enabled devices have lower-end CPU's and such).

My advice is to go for bitmap fonts or use individual PNG files for labels.